# loop through a json numeric array?

Tags: jquery, json

i use $.getJSON and here is my php file echo:ing back jsonstring

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    $nr[] = "nr" . $i;
}

$nr = json_encode($nr);

echo "{'result': 'error', 'count': '$nr'}";
```

how do i loop all the nr through with jquery html()?

i want to echo it back to webpage like:

nr 1
nr 2
nr 3
nr 4
nr 5
nr 6
nr 7
nr 8
nr 9
nr 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery, eval the "count" like

```
array_data=eval(json_data["count"])
```

php return this

```
{'result': 'error', 'count': '["nr1","nr2","nr3","nr4","nr5","nr6","nr7","nr8","nr9","nr10"]'}
```

Once you eval "count"

array_data will be `["nr1","nr2","nr3","nr4","nr5","nr6","nr7","nr8","nr9","nr10"]`

After that you can loop array_data

Comment: what if the count variable holds different string values?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('file.php', function(data){
  for(var i=0; i<data.count.length; i++){
    alert(i+": "+data.count[i]);
  }
});
```

edit: The problem is that the way you store it, the php array is stored as a string in the json. Try the following instead:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    $nr[] = "nr" . $i;
}
$ json = array('result' => 'error', 'count' => $nr);
echo json_encode($json);
```